# How to add primary key in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I already created a table(let's say contact info), but I forgot to create primary key.
Since I already entered some values in the table I want to keep the table and just want to add primary key column. How do I add primary key column on left side of the table with incremental numbers?

Comment: When you say *on the left side of the table* - why? Why does the position of the columns matter?

Comment: How about you create another temporary table, do an insert into new_tab select * from old_tab. Recreate the old_tab with auto increment then insert into old_tab select 1, a.* from new_tab. Drop the new_tab.

Comment: I know this can be a duplicated question, but no other Q&As has explanations

Comment: I wanted it to be left side because it looks nice and I get your point. But I am learning right now, so I need to know if there's such option exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an auto-incrementing column:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_info ADD COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand key words up to 'add column'. So this 'id Numeric' is just name of the column as primary key? It can be any name I want? 'Auto_increment' is the option for 'primary key' key word?

Comment: `id` is just the name of the column, you can call it what you want. `numeric` is its type (btw: it was a mistake - you should use `int`). `auto_increment` is indeed an additional neat option for key columns.

Comment: Not working! Key word 'Primary' shows as an syntax error in mySQL....strange...

Comment: @Sean works on my table... What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Nevermind, after changing numeric to int(10) primary key worked. What happens if you don't add auto_increment option?